# Consider the integrator and check for time invariance

Tags: continuous-signals, linear-systems, homework

I'm trying to check the following system for for time-invariance.

$$ y(t) = \int_0^t x(\lambda) d\lambda$$

Please explain me why it is time-invariant.

Comment: Could you explain why you think it is time-invariant?

Comment: I think it's a time-variant... but Is it time invariant?

Comment: You should show your calculations and your conclusions. We can't do your homework for you, but we can help you doing it.

Comment: You better add that to your question.

Comment: Check how I added the equation to your question (using Latex formatting), and use that to add the steps that you came up with.

Comment: First. y(t-k) = integral(0 to t-k)  x(u)  du        and then, Second,  I'll move the input which is x(t-k). That is integral(0 to t)  x(u-k) du.    it's same equation which is integral(-k to t-k)  x(T)  dT.     Compare first and second, I think it's not the same. so time variant.... is it right?

Comment: Yes, that's basically it.

Comment: then it's solution is the time-variant?

Comment: Yes. Why are you unsure about it?

Comment: professor said to me when you move input, you must move integral range also... he said, in my Second solution, it's right to integral(k to t)  x(u-k) du....... But I think it is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that there are different kinds of (causal) integrators. The one in your question with a fixed finite lower integration limit is not time-invariant, as you've shown yourself (in the comments).

Other variants are

$$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^tx(\tau)d\tau\tag{1}$$

and

$$y(t)=\int_{t-T}^tx(\tau)d\tau\tag{2}$$

Both of these integrators are time-invariant, which is straightforward to show.